# Issue With Playing mp4 and 3gp from server on VideoView In Application

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have an application where videos are recorded using the inbuilt camera, and then uploaded to a webserver. The videos are saved in mp4 and 3gp formats.The code excerpts to take the videos are:

```
       // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String mediaFile2;
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        preview_uri=mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                 + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
        pathname="IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".3gp");
        preview_uri= mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
        + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".3gp";
        pathname="VID_" + timeStamp + ".3gp";
    } else {
        return null;

          }
```

I upload them using a php script , and i use filezilla to confirm they are actually in the "video" folder. Also, typing in the address in my web browser, opens a download dialog to begin download of the file.

However, when i want to play the file in the application, it fails with the error message :

```
     "sorry, this video is not valid for streaming to this device"
```

This error is the same for mp4 and 3gp files. The code for the videoview is:

```
video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
video.setVideoPath(path);
video.requestFocus();
video.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    video.start();
  }
});
```

Also, no errors display in logcat and the videos play with vlc media player on my laptop. How can i resolve this?